# PhantomJS driver unable to create session on NodeJS and Selenium

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have an App that works just fine with Chrome, and I wanted to move to PhantomJS to make it work faster, since it has to go through many URLs.

```
const driver = new Builder()
  .forBrowser("chrome")
  .usingServer("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub")
  .build();
```

This code for creating my driver works just fine for `chrome` but when I replace `chrome` with `phantomjs` I get the following error:

```
SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create session from {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "browserName": "phantomjs"
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "browserName": "phantomjs"
      }
    ]
  }
}
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_301'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\\Desktop\\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:553:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\\Desktop\\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:635:13)
    at Executor.execute (C:\Users\\Desktop\\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:569:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5) {
  remoteStacktrace: ''
}
```

I have also downloaded and placed the `PhantomJS.exe` executable in my directory

Comment: Why did you decide to use phantomjs and not headless ChromeDriver?

Comment: I forgot that, this was a possibility, how do I set chrome to headless?

Comment: Setting ChromeDriver to headless mode is done by setting driver options to headless. The exact syntax depends on language you are using